# DBT set test severity for all test in a model

Tags: yaml, dbt

In DBT, I can configure the [severity of a test](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/severity) on either the project level or test level, like so:

**Project level:**

```yaml
tests:
  +severity: warn  # all tests
```

**Column/Test level:**

```yaml
models:
  - name: my_table
    columns:
      - name: my_column
        tests:
          - unique:
              config:
                severity: warn
```

I am trying to set the severity of all tests for a given model, but am getting a parsing error:

```yaml
models:
  - name: my_table
    tests:
        +severity: warn  # all tests
    columns:
      - name: my_column
        tests:
          - unique:
```

Is there a correct way to be doing this? Or should I create a feature request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest project and directory names under the `tests:` tag in your `dbt_project.yml` file:

```yaml
tests:
  jaffle_shop:  # project name
    staging:    # top-level dir inside models/ dir
      +severity: warn
```

See the [docs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/resource-path) on resource paths for more information.

Comment: Does this only work on the directory/schema level? Or can I apply this on the model level as well?

Comment: I see. It follows resource path, this is good.

Comment: the docs suggest that it should work to select a single model, but I just tried it and it didn't work: `[WARNING]: Configuration paths exist in your dbt_project.yml file which do not apply to any resources.
There are 1 unused configuration paths:
- tests.jaffle_shop.staging.stg_customers`
If you get the same error I'd open an issue. Selecting a single model definitely works for the `models:` key; I've never used it under `tests:` before

Comment: It looks like follows directories – more pythonic than other aspects of dbt ;)